# API testing using post man

Tags: testing, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I am new to api testing from postman.I went through several blogs and articles on
api testing.But I don't know how deeper we can done testing.
Also how can we write test for post request.I have the below department mode class
from my web api.

```
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Department Name")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

The sample get request i used is given below

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if(!body.DepartmentId)
{
tests["department id must exists in  response"]=true;
}
else
{
tests["department id exists in response"]=true;
}
if(typeof body.DepartmentName !='string')
{
tests["department name must be type string"]=true;
}
if(responseCode.name.has("OK"))
{
tests["Status code name has string OK"] = true;
}
```

Whether the above testing procedure is correct.?
   What all things to be tested while invoking a post request and get request against department controller for the above model.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to write 2 test cases to test for +ve and -ve scenario. All you need to do is write one test case and it will either pass or fail based on the scenario. For example lets consider your **DepartmentId**

The test case should be

```
tests["department id must exists in  response"]= body.DepartmentId? true : false;
```

Based on whether you department id exists or not either your test case will pass (marked green) or fail (marked red).

Alternatively if you are dealing with not only testing but also designing your APIs and documenting them then have a look at http://myapic.com. Its a great tool for end to end API design documenting and testing.